# Should I care about providing asynchronous calls in my go library?

Tags: go

I am developing a simple go library for jsonrpc over http.

There is the following method:

```
rpcClient.Call("myMethod", myParam1, myParam2)
```

This method internally does a http.Get() and returns the result or an error (tuple).

This is of course synchron for the caller and returns when the Get() call returns.

Is this the way to provide libraries in go? Should I leave it to the user of my library to make it asynchron if she wants to?

Or should I provide a second function called:

```
rpcClient.CallAsync()
```

and return a channel here? Because channels cannot provide tuples I have to pack the (response, error) tuple in a struct and return that struct instead.

Does this make sense?

Otherwise the user would have to wrap every call in an ugly method like:

```
result := make(chan AsyncResponse)
go func() {
    res, err := rpcClient.Call("myMethod", myParam1, myParam2)
    result <- AsyncResponse{res, err}
}()
```

Is there a best practice for go libraries and asynchrony?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole point of go's execution model is to hide the asynchronous operations from the developer, and behave like a threaded model with blocking operations. Behind the scenes there are green-threads and asynchronous IO and a very sophisticated scheduler.

So no, you shouldn't provide an async API to your library. Networking in go is done in a pseudo-blocking way from the code's perspective, and you open as many goroutines as needed, as they are very cheap.

So your last example is the way to go, and I don't consider it ugly. Because it allows the developer to choose the concurrency model. In the context of an http server, where each command is handled in separate goroutine, I'd just call `rpcClient.Call("myMethod", myParam1, myParam2)`.

Or if I want a fanout - I'll create fanout logic.

You can also create a convenience function for executing the call and returning on a channel:

```
func CallAsync(method, p1, p2) chan AsyncResponse {
    result := make(chan AsyncResponse)
    go func() {
        res, err := rpcClient.Call(method, p1, p2)
        result <- AsyncResponse{res, err}
    }()
    return result
}
```